# Common Encryption algorithm for Rails and Java

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, encryption, password-encryption

I am going to integrate two web applications written in different platforms (Java and Ruby),
I have to use common encryption algorithm for password in both application.

Is there any common encryption/decryption algorithm for both? If yes, please mention any useful link or any example.

It would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

In addition during my digging out it I found,

I have used Base64 with DES in both, interesting thing is that Characters and special characters give me same result in both but as i adding any number like (1,2,3), half of result is same and half encryption is something different.

*Ruby Code

```
 require 'openssl'
 require 'base64'

 c = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("des")
 c.encrypt 
 c.key ="REPPIFY_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

 e = c.update("ankit@123")
 e << c.final
 puts Base64.encode64(e)
```

Output: Cbe9GslMs8mh33jAOD9qsw==

*Java Code
I am defining only encryption method here:-

```
public static String encryptPassword(String pass) {

        public static final String DESKEY = "REPPIFY_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            System.out.println("Here is my password = "+pass);
        DESKeySpec keySpec = null;
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = null;
        SecretKey key = null;
        Cipher cipher = null;
        BASE64Encoder base64encoder = new BASE64Encoder();

        byte[] cleartext = null;
        String encrypedPwd = null;
            String pass = "ankit@123";

        try {
            keySpec = new DESKeySpec(DESKEY.getBytes("UTF8"));
            keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
            key = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
            if(pass!=null) {
                cleartext = pass.getBytes("UTF8");
                cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
                encrypedPwd = base64encoder.encode(cipher.doFinal(cleartext));
            }
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } // cipher is not thread safe 
        catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Here I am printing encrypted pwd = "+encrypedPwd);
        return encrypedPwd;
    }
```

Output in Java :- Cbe9GslMs8mWn9yTmZrUiw==

Comment: You should put this information in your question, so people can see if/that you made research effort.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the Ruby world, I'd recommend [BCrypt](https://rubygems.org/gems/bcrypt-ruby), which is also favored by popular authentication plugins like [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). I'm not very familiar with Java but a quick search suggests that there's BCrypt implementation in Java too:

http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/

EDIT - BCrypt is 1-way encryption, mainly for use in hashing passwords. If you are looking for something that will encrypt and decrypt then you'll have to look at something else. Seeing as you mentioned it's for passwords I'd suggest you only want 1-way encryption though.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer...just change a following line in ruby code and then you can use base64 decoder with DES in both:

***c = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("DES-ECB")***

```
require 'openssl'
 require 'base64'

 c = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("DES-ECB")
 c.encrypt 
c.key ="REPPIFY_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

 e = c.update("ankit@123")
 e << c.final
 puts Base64.encode64(e)
```